# How add custom icons from my pc to my ReactNative app (NativeBase TabBar Icon)

Tags: android, react-native, icons, native-base

* was imported from NativeBase Components
*I am using a "TabBar" that contains a  item
*The platform is Android

I designed many icons for my app, and i used several with the tag  however i need add a custom icon in the tag  but i can't. This the way that i   try used it.

Also... This the way i call the local icon:

const iconMore = require('../../../static/img/tabBarAndroid/more.png');

```
render() {
    return (
      <Tabs>
        <Tab
          heading={
            <TabHeading>
              <Icon name={iconHome} />
            </TabHeading>}
        >
          <NewsList />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          heading={
            <TabHeading>
              <Icon android={iconInterest} />
            </TabHeading>}
        >
         <FavoriteListComponent />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          heading={
            <TabHeading>
              <Icon android={iconSearchChurches} />
            </TabHeading>}
        >
         <MapChurchComponent />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          heading={
            <TabHeading>
              <Icon android={iconHeadquarters} />
            </TabHeading>}
        >
         <ChurchListComponent />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          heading={
            <TabHeading>
              <Icon android={iconMore} />
              </TabHeading>}
        >
         <MasComponent />
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Similar question asked on SO. Check [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/870) for updates

Comment: @SupriyaKalghatgi Yeah, i saw. Thnaks